# What does [x.x.x, ) mean in a packages.lock.json dependency?

Tags: .net, nuget

This syntax looks strange to me. It starts with a bracket, but ends in a trailing comma and parenthesis. What does `[x.x.x, )` mean in a *packages.lock.json* dependency?

```
"my.project.core": {
    "type": "Project",
    "dependencies": {
      "Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus": "[7.13.1, )",
      "Azure.Storage.Blobs": "[12.15.1, )",
      "Azure.Storage.Queues": "[12.13.1, )",
      "Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos": "[3.32.2, )",
      "Microsoft.Extensions.Azure": "[1.6.3, )",
      "Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory": "[6.0.1, )",
      "Microsoft.FeatureManagement.AspNetCore": "[2.5.1, )"
    }
  }
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/concepts/package-versioning#version-ranges

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [version range](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/concepts/package-versioning#version-ranges):

> When referring to package dependencies, NuGet supports using interval notation for specifying version ranges, summarized as follows:

> | Notation | Applied rule | Description |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1.0 | x ≥ 1.0 | Minimum version, inclusive |
> | **[1.0,)** | **x ≥ 1.0** | **Minimum version, inclusive** |
> | (1.0,) | x > 1.0 | Minimum version, exclusive |
> | [1.0] | x == 1.0 | Exact version match |
> | (,1.0] | x ≤ 1.0 | Maximum version, inclusive |
> | (,1.0) | x < 1.0 | Maximum version, exclusive |
> | [1.0,2.0] | 1.0 ≤ x ≤ 2.0 | Exact range, inclusive |
> | (1.0,2.0) | 1.0 < x < 2.0 | Exact range, exclusive |
> | [1.0,2.0) | 1.0 ≤ x < 2.0 | Mixed inclusive minimum and exclusive maximum version |
> | (1.0) | invalid | invalid |

I.e., in your case, you have the lock file fixing the minimum allowed version (`Minimum version, inclusive` the one with the `[1.0,)` example in the table).

Comment: `Minimum version, inclusive` - which should be the default, but sadly we are stuck with fixed versions...